# $wpdb query to sum SQL decimals from column where they match a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am building a WordPress plugin that uses custom tables I've built within the Wordpress data save. In one file I'm trying to add up all the values within a decimal column where the ID is equal to a queried ID. I have tried many solutions and nothing seems to work. The current solution seems to provide an answer however it is the wrong one.

```
/* Sum payments made to invoice number */

$payments_table = $wpdb->prefix . "_payments";

$invoice_id = '999999999';


$result = $wpdb->query('SELECT sum(value) FROM '.$payments_table.' WHERE invoice_id = '.$invoice_id.'');

echo $result;
```

In the database there are currently two payments of '0.001' for invoice '999999999' so I would expect the sum to be '0.002' however the code returns '1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use get_results for fetch results.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT sum(value) as result_value FROM '.$payments_table.' WHERE invoice_id = '.$invoice_id.'');

print_r($result);
echo $result[0]->result_value;
```

Use this.
It's work.